# RunTime Error on VBA Macro

Tags: regex, vba, excel, runtime-error

I am working on VBA code to grab text from an Outlook email and place it in an Excel sheet I have set up.  I am using Excel 2010.  My email contains the 
following information:

**Company: ABC Company

 Class Period: 2013-10-29 through 2014-10-22**

I have set up a For With loop to go through the email and insert the Company Name in column A, the first date (2013-10-29) in the column B and the other date (2014-10-22) in the column C. When I run my code I receive an error that states: Run-time error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument on the below line of code:
`vText2 = Trim(M.SubMatches(2))`

Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong. Part of my code is below.  Let me know if I need to provide any additional information.

```
sText = olItem.Body

Set Reg1 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

For i = 1 To 3

With Reg1
Select Case i
Case 1
.Pattern(Company\s[:]+\s(\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*\s*)\n)"
.Global = False
Case 2
.Pattern = "(Class Period\s*[:]+\s*([\d-\s]*))"
.Global = False
Case 3
.Pattern = "(through+\s*([\d-\s]*))"
.Global = False
End Select

End With

If Reg1.Test(sText) Then

Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(sText)
For Each M In M1
vText = Trim(M.SubMatches(1))
vText2 = Trim(M.SubMatches(2))
vText3 = Trim(M.SubMatches(3))
Next
End If
Next i

xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = vText
xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = vText2
xlSheet.Range("C" & rCount) = vText3

xlWB.Close 1
```

Comment: I think you wanted to write `.Pattern = "(Company` and not `.Pattern(Company`. Also, `\d-\s` is not valid, use `\d\s-`. I also think threre is no submatch(3) in your patterns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is saying that the argument you gave it (the index) is invalid for the SubMatches collection because it exceeds the count of items in the collection.

Remember too that the SubMatches index starts at "0".  I'm assuming that you intentionally skipped the first item in favor of the second through fourth items in the collection.

I think you are expecting it to be adding the match to the collection each time it runs through the for loop.  That's not the case.  The new match is replacing the old match so you only ever have one result to work with at a time.

Try something like this instead:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    sText = "Company: ABC Company" & vbNewLine & "Class Period: 2013-10-29 through 2014-10-22" & vbNewLine
    Set Reg1 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    vText = "Missing"
    vText2 = "Missing"
    vText3 = "Missing"

    For i = 1 To 3

        With Reg1
            Select Case i
            Case 1
                .Pattern = "(Company)\w*[:](.*?)\n"
                .Global = False
            Case 2
                .Pattern = "(Class Period\s*[:]+\s*([\d-\s]*))"
                .Global = False
            Case 3
                .Pattern = "(through+\s*([\d-\s]*))"
                .Global = False
            End Select

        End With


        If Reg1.Test(sText) Then
            Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(sText)
            For Each M In M1
                If M.SubMatches.Count > 0 Then
                    Select Case i
                    Case 1
                        vText = Trim(M.SubMatches(1))
                    Case 2
                        vText2 = Trim(M.SubMatches(1))
                    Case 3
                        vText3 = Trim(M.SubMatches(1))
                    End Select
                End If
            Next
        End If

        Next i

        xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = vText
        xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = vText2
        xlSheet.Range("C" & rCount) = vText3

        xlWB.Close 1

    End Sub
```

Note that I had to change your Company regex to get it to work too.  Your original one wasn't working for me.

Comment: Thank you.  I tested each regular expression individually and received the desired result.  I input the code that you provided.  The first column provides the date 2014-10-22 instead of ABC Company and the next two columns are "Missing".

Comment: @user3483327 - OK.  I think I better understand what's going on now.  I edited my answer.